# Firefox: Security warning popup for http links having parameters from https page

Tags: http, security, firefox, https

Firefox shows a security warning popup ("sensitive data sent over http") when clicking on http links having parameters (i.e. http://www.example.com/mypage.php?param=value) from an https page.

Why **Chrome, Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge does not complain/show this security warning popup?**

As far as I understand, links with parameters should not necessarily be considered as "sending data". I didn't find any documentation in google about this issue. **Is this a known bug in Firefox**?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug, it's a security feature. :) Any data (any parameter a page can put on a link) on a page downloaded over https is potentially sensitive. Therefore, sending it over plain http is a potential security issue, that's why Firefox warns the user.

Other browsers may not be so strict about this, but it's a nice reminder that it's not good and not very defendable to use plain http anymore, when certificates are practically free.